# When you clone a repo like Laravel into an existing project do you pull it in as submodule even if you're not planning to contribute?

Tags: git, github

I'm confused on what you do when you've created your own project repo, and then I want to add another repo to it like Laravel 4.  It seems from [Git Pro](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) that submodules might be what I want, and if it is the way to do this will conflict arise with regards to similarly named files like readme.md?  Is this what I'm looking for or is there another solution?

UPDATE:
Currently I'm cloning [laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) into my /root, then **deleting the associated .git folder**, then cloning our base installation files that include package.json, bower.json, /docs, /config/, etc etc etc; into my /root, **deleting that .git folder**, then invoking composer install and npm install, running git init, and finally pushing it the projects remote git repo on BitBucket.  The deleting of .git for each cloned repo seems weird (which started this question), so I thought submodules after some searching, but submodules install to subfolders, which I don't want since that doesn't allow for all the CLI to be at a single level, among other things.

Comment: Your update illustrates that submodules wouldn't work indeed. But that simply not how you would version a Laravel project, as I mention below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need submodules.
Once [Laravel is installed](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation), you can follow this [Laravel recipe](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/31/managing-your-project-with-git) to manage your application with Git, provided your application is a Laravel project.

```
laravel:~$ cd myapp
laravel:~/myapp$ git init
```

> Notice the file composer.lock is not tracked? You should edit `.gitignore` and removed the line that has `composer.lock` in it. This way you'll be tracking `composer.lock` too.
>
> When you track `composer.lock` with your source code control system it allows you to do a `composer update` on your development machine and then, later, a `composer install` on your production machine.
>   The `composer install` command will make sure all packages are the correct version as specified in the `composer.lock` file. Thus production uses not only the same packages, but the same versions of the packages as your production machine

```
laravel:~/myapp$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
laravel:~/myapp$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"

laravel:~/myapp$ git add .
laravel:~/myapp$ git commit -m "initial checkin"
```

Comment: Hi, so I can do what you've done here, and that works great, but I'm still pulling in our base install files into the root, and deleting the .git folder and then running git init.  Is there a way to eliminate having to do this as well?

Comment: @mtpultz not sure, unless you follow the Laravel installation process (instead of cloning the Laravel repo)

Comment: It a good step in the right direction, so I'll do this for now, and just drop in our base project repo by hand till something better presents itself.  Thanks for the help