# Why is all of the commits for the Laravel framework visible in my projects git log?

Tags: git, laravel

Why is all of the commits associated with Laravel visible in some of my projects when I run `git log --all` and not in others. Git docs says:

> `--all`: Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/`, along with `HEAD`, are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

In my `.git/refs/` all I see is empty folders, probably because all the refs have been packed.

How can I get rid of the Laravel commit history as well as the tags, but preserve my own history and tags?

Comment: You have the framework as a submodule?

Comment: Did you create the project by cloning the laravel repo?

Comment: No submodules are listed when I run `git submodule`

Comment: Yes, I recall that I've might have started the project by cloning the framework repo a long time ago.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27717843/4881811)!

Comment: This is a 2+ year old projects with lots and lots of commits already. I don't want to preserve the commit history, not start a new project.

Comment: I guess another wording for your problem would be, "how to remove commits older than X". Maybe try something from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515580/how-do-i-remove-the-old-history-from-a-git-repository .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Push to a remove by running `git push --follow-tags` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438076/2575503) post)
2. Clone the repo down again using `git clone <repo>`

Voilà. All unwanted refs gone.